# crispy forms adding is-invalid class to my fields before form submission

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am using Django. I have created my forms as below

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    body = forms.CharField(max_length=10000, required=True,widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":"5"}))
    from_location = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    to_location = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
```

views.py

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        print('printing title..')
        if request.method == 'POST':

            if post_form.is_valid():
                post = Post.objects.create(title = request.POST['title'], body=request.POST['body'], from_location=request.POST['from_location'], to_location=request.POST['to_location'], author = request.user, uuid = uuid.uuid4())
                message = messages.success(request, f'Your post has been created!')
                return redirect(reverse_lazy('posts:post'))

    else:
        post_form = PostForm()
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('posts:post'))
    context = {
        'post_form':post_form
    }

    return render(request, 'posts/create_post.html', context)
```

I am getting a red border on all the form fields. I realized that crispy-forms has added the class `is-invalid` to all the fields making this. If I make required=False in forms, the error is gone.

Current output

[image: Screenshot of output]

expected output is the image above without the red borders and warnings

I  tried removing the class from dev tools and it worked. I asked chatGPT and tried its methods, but it did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this issue because in your views.py file `post_form = PostForm(request.POST)` is outside of the `if request.method == 'POST'` POST request check.

**Update your views.py file to this:**

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            post_form = PostForm(request.POST)

            if post_form.is_valid():
                post = Post.objects.create(title=request.POST['title'], body=request.POST['body'], from_location=request.POST['from_location'], to_location=request.POST['to_location'], author=request.user, uuid=uuid.uuid4())
                messages.success(request, f'Your post has been created!')
                return redirect(reverse_lazy('posts:post'))
        else:
            post_form = PostForm()
    else:
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('posts:post'))

    context = {
        'post_form': post_form
    }

    return render(request, 'posts/create_post.html', context)
```

This will solve the form validity issue on render on the page. You should always check the form method request first before rendering the form on the page or passing the `request.POST` form data.